# How to convert a variable containing sed-arguments to an array?

Tags: bash, sed

I'm using

```
sed (GNU sed) 4.4
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

I've a complicated set of sed arguments in a bash script, about 20 different `-e expression`.  Here is a simple example as a one-liner. It converts `aa bb cc` to `aaBBcc`:

```
sed -e 's# ##g' -e 's#b#B#g' <<< "aa bb cc"
```

or

```
k=('-e' 's# ##g'    '-e' 's#b#B#g'); sed "${k[@]}" <<< "aa bb cc"
```

However, there are 20-ish `-e expression` and most are complicated. The script is only for me, so it doesn't have to follow convention or policy.  To make the arguments readable / editable (to me), I assign them to a variable with extra whitespace, columnated, indented .... Here is a simplified version of what I mean:

```
#!/bin/bash
k="-e s#    #    #g \
   -e s# b  # B  #g \
  "
```

That simplified example doesn't show how useful that approach is to me. Anyway, here is the "working" script:

```
#!/bin/bash
k="-e s#    #    #g \
   -e s# b  # B  #g \
  "
k=$(sed -e 's# ##g'         <<< "$k")  #1 remove all spaces
k=$(sed -e 's|###|# ##|g'   <<< "$k")  #2 put needed space back in
k=$(sed -e 's#-e#|-e #g'    <<< "$k")  #3 delimit the args with "|"
k=$(sed -e 's#|##'          <<< "$k")  #4 remove the leading "|"
z=$IFS; IFS="|"; k=($k); IFS=$z        #5 convert variable to array
sed "${k[@]}" <<< "aa bb cc"           #6 process the string
```

Output is:

```
aaBBcc
```

It works and it is readable for me. But it is really complicated, and took me quite awhile to figure out how to massage `k` into a form that sed would take.

It fails to work if I quote the expressions, as in `-e 's#b#B#g'`

Is there a less complicated way, and/or a way to quote the expressions?  **Must work with `k` whitespaced as above,** sed 4.4, bash 4.4.12(1).

#######################################################

added 2022-09-26 14:58 PST:

Here is a real world script for converting a URL before bookmarking.  The caveat is that I wrote for my usage.  I don't have to figure out what the code is trying to do because I already know the paradigm, I invented it, or reinvented it.

```
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=123456&_nkw=%28vintage%2Cvtg%29+%28polartec%2Cfleece%29+%28full%2Czip%2Czips%2Czipper%2Czippered%2Czipping%29+-%28hilfiger%2C%22old+navy%22%2Chooded%2Ccamo%2Ccamouflage%2Cvest%2Csmall%2Cmedium%2Cxl%2Cxxl%2Chalf%2Cquarter%2C%221%2F4%22%2C%221%2F2%22%2C+lined%2Cwinnie%2Ctoddler%2Ckids%2Cladies%2Cwomens%2Cwomen%29&_sacat=11450&LH_TitleDesc=0&_odkw=%28vintage%2Cvtg%29+fleece+%28full%2Czip%2Czips%2Czipper%2Czippered%2Czipping%29+-%28hilfiger%2C%22old+navy%22%2Chooded%2Ccamo%2Ccamouflage%2Cvest%2Csmall%2Cmedium%2Cxl%2Cxxl%2Chalf%2Cquarter%2C%221%2F4%22%2C%221%2F2%22%2C+lined%2Cwinnie%2Ctoddler%2Ckids%2Cladies%2Cwomens%2Cwomen%29&_osacat=11450&_sop=10&LH_PrefLoc=3&_ipg=240&_udhi=99
```

into

```
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?&_nkw=(vintage,vtg)+(polartec,fleece)+(full,zip,zips,zipper,zippered,zipping)+-(hilfiger,old+navy,hooded,camo,camouflage,vest,small,medium,xl,xxl,half,quarter,1/4,1/2,+lined,winnie,toddler,kids,ladies,womens,women)&_sacat=1145011450&_sop=10&LH_PrefLoc=3&_udhi=99&_ipg=240
```

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
k="-e s# [&]*_from=R40      #            #   \
   -e s# [&]*_trk[^&]*      #            #   \
   -e s# [&]*_odkw[^&]*     #            #   \
   -e s# [&]*_osacat[^&]    #            #   \
   -e s# [&]*_sacat=0       #            #   \
   -e s# [&]*LH_TitleDesc=0 #            #   \
   -e s# ++                 # +          #g  \
   -e s# %2F                # /          #g  \
   -e s# %28                # (          #g  \
   -e s# %29                # )          #g  \
   -e s# %2C                # ,          #g  \
   -e s# %22                #            #g  \
   -e s# &_ipg=[0-9]*       #            #   \
   -e s# $                  # \&_ipg=240 #   \
   "
k=$(sed -e 's# ##g'         \
        -e 's|###|# ##|g'   \
        -e 's#-e#|-e #g'    \
        -e 's#|##'          \
        <<< "$k"            \
   )
z=$IFS; IFS="|"; k=($k); IFS=$z        
sed "${k[@]}" <<< "$1"
```

Comment: "Must work with k whitespaced as above" -- why? If you want extra whitespace in the regular expressions so they are more readable, use perl and the `x` flag for the `s///` function.

Comment: I knew before posting this that people would suggest other languages that they happen to have under their belt, so i put: **Must work with** k whitespaced as above, **sed** 4.4, bash 4.4.12(1).  But your comment about perl will certainly help other readers.

Comment: I understand the sed requirement. It was the **must ... whitespace** requirement that I am questioning.

Comment: I knew before I posted that the simplicity of my example wouldn't convince people of the utility (for me) of the white space.  So I included a statement to that regard and just trusted people to accept the utility of the white space to me.  Here is an unrelated real-world (for me) but limited example, also for my `sed` usage:  `k="GGy   LjU   1Vw  9Wd"; echo "("$(sed -E 's# +#|#g' <<< $k)")"` .  I'd much rather have to maintain `GGy   KjU   RVw  9Wd` than `(GGy|LjU|1Vw|9Wd)`.  Anyway I see so many posts here where posters don't boil their the code examples down to what is important.

Comment: This is why I invoked perl, it allows the extra whitespace. Good luck, I hope you get some more suggestions.

Comment: My lifetime usage of perl is about 60 minutes, sad to say. I added my current work above, which finally prompted me to post here.  I wish I could get it to work when the `sed` expressions are quoted, as in `-e 's#b#B#g'` but the FAq link you posted explained why that may never be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use `;` to join multiple set operations into a single parameter? Something like this:

```
k="s#    #    #g;
   s# b  # B  #g;
"
k=$(sed 's# ##g; s|###|# ##|g' <<<"$k") # Clean up spaces in $k
sed "$k" <<< "aa bb cc"
```

Result: "aaBBcc". Your big pattern would look like this:

```
k="s# [&]*_from=R40      #            #   ;
   s# [&]*_trk[^&]*      #            #   ;
   s# [&]*_odkw[^&]*     #            #   ;
   s# [&]*_osacat[^&]    #            #   ;
   s# [&]*_sacat=0       #            #   ;
   s# [&]*LH_TitleDesc=0 #            #   ;
   s# ++                 # +          #g  ;
   s# %2F                # /          #g  ;
   s# %28                # (          #g  ;
   s# %29                # )          #g  ;
   s# %2C                # ,          #g  ;
   s# %22                #            #g  ;
   s# &_ipg=[0-9]*       #            #   ;
   s# $                  # \&_ipg=240 #   ;
   "
```

You could also do the whitespace-mangling as part of the `sed` command with a command substitution:

```
sed "$(sed 's# ##g; s|###|# ##|g' <<<"$k")" <<< "$1"
```

Comment: Wow, super clean.  I was not aware of being able to combine in that manner. Thought it had to be `sed -e <expr1> -e <expr2>` or `-E`

Comment: @Will The `-e` isn't needed if there's only one command string (i.e. just one argument). Separating commands with `;` doesn't seem to be mentioned in the man page (weird!), but it works fine in all versions of `sed` I've tried it with. BTW, the `-E` option does something completely different (it switches to extended regex syntax).

Comment: @Gordon_Davisson  Maybe the `;` is in the documentation for `-f` script-file syntax. Dropping the `-e`s will clean up my future usage, thanks. Sometimes I make use of the features that come with `-E`.  The thing I struggle with most is quantifiers. I often struggle to get `+` and `{n}` to work.  I ought to pick up books on `sed` and `regex` for casual reading.

Answer (score 3):

See [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

You want

```bash
k=(
    -e 's/ //g'
    -e 's/b/B/g'
)
sed "${k@]}" ...
```

Even if this code is only for you, you'll never be able to maintain what you have after ignoring it for a while. Readability and good practice is good for you too.

---

Given your updated real-life example, here's another thought:

```bash
declare -a regex str flag cmds

regex+=( '[&]*_from=R40'      ); str+=( ''           ); flag+=( ''  )
regex+=( '[&]*_trk[^&]*'      ); str+=( ''           ); flag+=( ''  )
regex+=( '[&]*_odkw[^&]*'     ); str+=( ''           ); flag+=( ''  )
regex+=( '[&]*_osacat[^&]'    ); str+=( ''           ); flag+=( ''  )
regex+=( '[&]*_sacat=0'       ); str+=( ''           ); flag+=( ''  )
regex+=( '[&]*LH_TntleDesc=0' ); str+=( ''           ); flag+=( ''  )
regex+=( '++'                 ); str+=( '+'          ); flag+=( 'g' )
regex+=( '%2F'                ); str+=( '\/'         ); flag+=( 'g' )
# note the backslash in the "str" value: ^^ -- that's the "s///" delimiter
regex+=( '%28'                ); str+=( '('          ); flag+=( 'g' )
regex+=( '%29'                ); str+=( ')'          ); flag+=( 'g' )
regex+=( '%2C'                ); str+=( ','          ); flag+=( 'g' )
regex+=( '%22'                ); str+=( ''           ); flag+=( 'g' )
regex+=( '&_npg=[0-9]*'       ); str+=( ''           ); flag+=( ''  )
regex+=( '$'                  ); str+=( '\&_npg=240' ); flag+=( ''  )

n=${#regex[@]}
for ((i=0; i < n; i++)); do
    cmds+=( -e "s/${regex[i]}/${str[i]}/${flag[i]}" )
done

url='https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=123456&_nkw=%28vintage%2Cvtg%29+%28polartec%2Cfleece%29+%28full%2Czip%2Czips%2Czipper%2Czippered%2Czipping%29+-%28hilfiger%2C%22old+navy%22%2Chooded%2Ccamo%2Ccamouflage%2Cvest%2Csmall%2Cmedium%2Cxl%2Cxxl%2Chalf%2Cquarter%2C%221%2F4%22%2C%221%2F2%22%2C+lined%2Cwinnie%2Ctoddler%2Ckids%2Cladies%2Cwomens%2Cwomen%29&_sacat=11450&LH_TitleDesc=0&_odkw=%28vintage%2Cvtg%29+fleece+%28full%2Czip%2Czips%2Czipper%2Czippered%2Czipping%29+-%28hilfiger%2C%22old+navy%22%2Chooded%2Ccamo%2Ccamouflage%2Cvest%2Csmall%2Cmedium%2Cxl%2Cxxl%2Chalf%2Cquarter%2C%221%2F4%22%2C%221%2F2%22%2C+lined%2Cwinnie%2Ctoddler%2Ckids%2Cladies%2Cwomens%2Cwomen%29&_osacat=11450&_sop=10&LH_PrefLoc=3&_ipg=240&_udhi=99'

sed "${cmds[@]}" <<< "$url"
```

```
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?&_nkw=(vintage,vtg)+(polartec,fleece)+(full,zip,zips,zipper,zippered,zipping)+-(hilfiger,old+navy,hooded,camo,camouflage,vest,small,medium,xl,xxl,half,quarter,1/4,1/2,+lined,winnie,toddler,kids,ladies,womens,women)&_sacat=11450&LH_TitleDesc=011450&_sop=10&LH_PrefLoc=3&_ipg=240&_udhi=99&_npg=240
```

Comment: I know the simplified example doesn't show it, but the crux for me developing the code and later understanding and maintaining the code is the argument list, not massaging it for `sed`.  I might also add that with your approach, there is no need for `k` in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for the link, which explains: ".... the single quotes inside the variable are literal, not syntactical ..."

Comment: Also, arbitrary whitespace is allowed in an array definition. The newlines really help: no need for line continuations.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that. Still if I were to take up your strategy, I'd opt for line continuation and get rid of `k` altogether

Comment: On the command line, the loop is hanging.  This completes `for ((i=0; i < n; i++)); do echo $i; done`  but this doesn't `unset cmds;for ((i=0; i < n; i++)); do cmds+=( -e "s/${regex[i]}/${str[i]}/${flag[i]" ); done`

Comment: missing closing `}` for `flag`

Comment: Yeah I fixed that. Note the comment

Comment: If I quote the expressions with `do cmds+=( -e "'s/${regex[i]}/${str[i]}/${flag[i]}'" )`, it breaks, but of course the FAQ that you linked to says this is expecterd since the single-quotes are literals.

Comment: Personal preference of course, but since yours doesn't allow the expressions to be quoted (nor does mine), I prefer mine for three reasons. **1)** If I'm going to loop, might as well create `k` as an array and loop through it to parse out the whitespace.  **2)** Fewer characters. and **3)**  lines like `-e s# [&]*_from=R40 [&]*_from=R40      #            #g` are more literal since the data is already embedded in the destination, the data being `[&]*_from=R40` and ``, and the desitnation being `-e s#<data>#<data>#`.

Comment: OK, it's your question. You seem pretty resistant to new ideas though.

Comment: I used your idea, see my answer below.  I'd say your help has been very helpful thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Combining @glenn_jackman answer with my idiosyncrasies:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a k
k=('-e s#  [&]*_from=R40       #              #   '
   '-e s#  [&]*_trk[^&]*       #              #   '
   '-e s#  [&]*_odkw[^&]*      #              #   '
   '-e s#  [&]*_osacat[^&]     #              #   '
   '-e s#  [&]*_sacat=0        #              #   '
   '-e s#  [&]*LH_TitleDesc=0  #              #   '
   '-e s#  ++                  #  +           #g  '
   '-e s#  %2F                 #  /           #g  '
   '-e s#  %28                 #  (           #g  '
   '-e s#  %29                 #  )           #g  '
   '-e s#  %2C                 #  ,           #g  '
   '-e s#  %22                 #              #g  '
   '-e s#  &_ipg=[0-9]*        #              #   '
   '-e s#  $                   #  \&_ipg=240  #   '
)

n=${#k[@]}
for ((i=0; i<n; i++)); do
  k[i]=$(sed -e 's% *# *%#%g' <<< "${k[i]}")
done
sed "${k[@]}" <<< "$1"
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a k
k+=('-e s#  [&]*_from=R40       #              #   ')
k+=('-e s#  [&]*_trk[^&]*       #              #   ')
k+=('-e s#  [&]*_odkw[^&]*      #              #   ')
k+=('-e s#  [&]*_osacat[^&]     #              #   ')
k+=('-e s#  [&]*_sacat=0        #              #   ')
k+=('-e s#  [&]*LH_TitleDesc=0  #              #   ')
k+=('-e s#  ++                  #  +           #g  ')
k+=('-e s#  %2F                 #  /           #g  ')
k+=('-e s#  %28                 #  (           #g  ')
k+=('-e s#  %29                 #  )           #g  ')
k+=('-e s#  %2C                 #  ,           #g  ')
k+=('-e s#  %22                 #              #g  ')
k+=('-e s#  &_ipg=[0-9]*        #              #   ')
k+=('-e s#  $                   #  \&_ipg=240  #   ')

n=${#k[@]}
for ((i=0; i<n; i++)); do
  k[i]=$(sed -e 's| *# *|#|g' <<< "${k[i]}")
done
sed "${k[@]}" <<< "$1"
exit
```